# R言語　オブジェクトの中身のアクセス

Tags: r

オブジェクトの中身のアクセス方法を教えていただきたいです。
具体的には，，，

```
sex<-c("F","M","M","M","F")
number<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
x<-data.frame(SEX=sex,NUMBER=number)

y<-c(1,2,4)
```

このような時，，，

```
c<-subset(x,NUMBER!=y)
```

上記のようにやりたいのですが，上手くいきません
つまり，最後はNUMBERのところを3,5だけ残したいです。

質問の仕方がへたくそで分かりにくいですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `c <- subset(x, !(NUMBER %in% y))`

Answer (score 0):

```
> x[!(x$NUMBER %in% y), ]

  SEX NUMBER
3   M      3
5   F      5
```

ですね。%in%演算子で複数の条件とのマッチですね。